# How to insert null value for datetime field in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to insert null `value` from front end. This is my code:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtCallTwo.Text))
        {
            DateTime second = DateTime.ParseExact(txtCallTwo.Text.Trim(), "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            objclsConsultantLeadStatusProp.dtDate_2nd_Call = second;
        }
        else
        {
            DateTime second = DateTime.ParseExact(txtCallTwo.Text.Trim(), "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            objclsConsultantLeadStatusProp.dtDate_2nd_Call = null;

        }
```

`dtDate_2nd_Call` property is declared as as `Datetime`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make dtDate_2nd_Call as `nullable` property. Syntax for nullable property is like this.

```
DateTime? dt = null;
```

For your case it should be `Datetime? dtDate_2nd_Call` instead of `Datetime dtDate_2nd_Call`

Comment: While designing the class for obejct `objclsConsultantLeadStatusProp`, define the property `dtDate_2nd_Call` as :
`Nullable<DateTime> dtDate_2nd_Call = null`

Comment: dtDate_2nd_Call is already in format DateTime? dtDate_2nd_Call.

Comment: I am saying to make it nullable, if you see closely, there is `?` beside `DateTime`.

Comment: @Rachna , if you don't use `nullable` property and assign `null` value to `datetime` field, it will show compilation error - `Cannot convert null to 'System.DateTime' because it is a non-nullable value type`

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is pretty simple. I am not sure if it is of any help to you now...

The DateTime data structure in .NET does not accept null values and thus gives you the error, the simple solution to this is adding a question mark without spaces next to DateTime, i.e., DateTime?

DateTime? data structure accepts null values and thus you won't get the error.